how can I passthrough intel gpu in pve 8.2.2
I was try passthrough intel gpu in pve, following by a blog:https://www.derekseaman.com/2023/11/proxmox-ve-8-1-windows-11-vgpu-vt-d-passthrough-with-intel-alder-lake.html
my environment：
CPU：    N100
PVE：    8.2.2
Kernel： 6.5.13-3-pve
I have a same typeof cpu with this blog (N100-N305, 12 gen alder lake)，same kernel，but i have this error, I not really good at linux, chatgpt give me nothing but crap, can anybody give me a hand.
by the way, if you need more info, I will reply very soon, I been doing this for weeks and I'd to die.
error:
root@jayj:~# dmesg | grep i915
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve root=/dev/mapper/pve-root ro quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt i915.enable_guc=3 i915.max_vfs=7
[    0.024042] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve root=/dev/mapper/pve-root ro quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt i915.enable_guc=3 i915.max_vfs=7
[    5.185418] i915: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    5.765684] i915 0000:00:02.0: Running in SR-IOV PF mode
[    5.766450] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    5.766708] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    5.767052] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Using Transparent Hugepages
[    5.768237] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    5.771411] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/adlp_dmc.bin (v2.20)
[    5.772244] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_ops [i915])
[    5.779427] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GuC firmware i915/tgl_guc_70.bin version 70.20.0
[    5.779434] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc.bin version 7.9.3
[    5.784449] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC: authenticated for all workloads!
[    5.784867] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: submission enabled
[    5.784871] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: SLPC enabled
[    5.785261] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC RC: enabled
[    5.786157] mei_pxp 0000:00:16.0-fbf6fcf1-96cf-4e2e-a6a6-1bab8cbe36b1: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_pxp_tee_component_ops [i915])
[    5.786321] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Protected Xe Path (PXP) protected content support initialized
[    5.892255] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    5.894232] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.894672] i915 0000:00:02.0: 7 VFs could be associated with this PF
[    5.923305] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    6.010529] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    8.451430] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    8.451534] i915 0000:00:02.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.451565] i915 0000:00:02.1: Running in SR-IOV VF mode
[    8.452119] i915 0000:00:02.1: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Unable to confirm version 1.9 (0000000000000000)
[    8.452186] i915 0000:00:02.1: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Found interface version 0.1.9.0
[    8.452746] i915 0000:00:02.1: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    8.452779] i915 0000:00:02.1: [drm] Using Transparent Hugepages
[    8.453491] i915 0000:00:02.1: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Unable to confirm version 1.9 (0000000000000000)
[    8.453554] i915 0000:00:02.1: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Found interface version 0.1.9.0
[    8.453946] i915 0000:00:02.1: GuC firmware PRELOADED version 0.0 submission:SR-IOV VF
[    8.453949] i915 0000:00:02.1: HuC firmware PRELOADED
[    8.456932] i915 0000:00:02.1: [drm] Protected Xe Path (PXP) protected content support initialized
[    8.456944] i915 0000:00:02.1: [drm] PMU not supported for this GPU.
[    8.457117] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.1 on minor 1
[    8.459262] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    8.459269] i915 0000:00:02.1: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    8.459443] i915 0000:00:02.2: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.459495] i915 0000:00:02.2: Running in SR-IOV VF mode
[    8.459871] i915 0000:00:02.2: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Unable to confirm version 1.9 (0000000000000000)
[    8.459959] i915 0000:00:02.2: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Found interface version 0.1.9.0
[    8.461355] i915 0000:00:02.2: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    8.461401] i915 0000:00:02.2: [drm] Using Transparent Hugepages
[    8.462272] i915 0000:00:02.2: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Unable to confirm version 1.9 (0000000000000000)
[    8.462492] i915 0000:00:02.2: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Found interface version 0.1.9.0
[    8.463006] i915 0000:00:02.2: GuC firmware PRELOADED version 0.0 submission:SR-IOV VF
[    8.463010] i915 0000:00:02.2: HuC firmware PRELOADED
[    8.466769] i915 0000:00:02.2: [drm] Protected Xe Path (PXP) protected content support initialized
[    8.466781] i915 0000:00:02.2: [drm] PMU not supported for this GPU.
[    8.466994] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.2 on minor 2
[    8.469187] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    8.469194] i915 0000:00:02.1: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=none
[    8.469199] i915 0000:00:02.2: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    8.469346] i915 0000:00:02.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.469395] i915 0000:00:02.3: Running in SR-IOV VF mode
[    8.472115] i915 0000:00:02.3: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Unable to confirm version 1.9 (0000000000000000)
[    8.472350] i915 0000:00:02.3: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Found interface version 0.1.9.0
[    8.473152] i915 0000:00:02.3: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    8.473222] i915 0000:00:02.3: [drm] Using Transparent Hugepages
[    8.474167] i915 0000:00:02.3: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Unable to confirm version 1.9 (0000000000000000)
[    8.474397] i915 0000:00:02.3: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: IOV: Found interface version 0.1.9.0
[    8.475096] i915 0000:00:02.3: GuC firmware PRELOADED version 0.0 submission:SR-IOV VF
[    8.475102] i915 0000:00:02.3: HuC firmware PRELOADED
[    8.477916] i915 0000:00:02.3: [drm] Protected Xe Path (PXP) protected content support initialized
[    8.477925] i915 0000:00:02.3: [drm] PMU not supported for this GPU.
[    8.478041] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.3 on minor 3
[    8.478272] i915 0000:00:02.0: Enabled 3 VFs


problem solved, it's a bug of i915-sriov-dkms, check https://github.com/strongtz/i915-sriov-dkms/pull/159
